# Simple Factory Pattern Demo

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to create a simple factory pattern demo in PHP. I am not sure if my codes are the best practice. It seems that I have some duplicated codes but I am not sure how to improve it. Basically, I want to create 3 types of accounts (basic, premium and vip). Please advise. Thanks a lot.

abstract class

```
abstract class User {

    function __construct() {
        $this->db= new Database('mysql','localhost','mvcdb','root','');
    }

    abstract function checkUser();

    function showAccountCredit(){
        return $this->credits;
    }
    function getUserName(){
        return $this->username;
    }


}
```

I have 3 different user account types:

Basic Account

```
class BasicUser extends User {

    function __construct($username) {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->username=$username;
        $this->credit='10';
        $this->accountType='Basic Account';

        $data=$this->checkUser();

        if(!empty($data)){
            echo 'The username: '.$this->username.' already exists<br>';
            return false;
        }

        $array=array('username'=>$this->username, 'password'=>'password','credit'=> $this->credit,'accountType'=>$this->accountType);
        $this->db->insert('user',$array);

    }


     function checkUser(){

        $array=array(':username'=>$this->username);
        $results=$this->db->select('SELECT * FROM USER WHERE username=:username',$array);
        if(!empty($results)){
        $this->credit=$results[0]['credit'];
        $this->accountType=$results[0]['accountType'];
        }

        return $results;

    }

    function showAccountCredit() {
        echo 'Username: '.$this->username.'<br>';
        echo 'Account Credit: '.$this->credit.'<br>';
        echo 'Account Type: '.$this->accountType;
    }

}
```

Premium Account

```
class PremiumUser extends User {

    function __construct($username) {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->username=$username;
        $this->credit='100';
        $this->accountType='Premium Account';

        $data=$this->checkUser();

        if(!empty($data)){
            echo 'The username: '.$this->username.' already exists<br>';
            return false;
        }

        $array=array('username'=>$this->username, 'password'=>'password','credit'=> $this-                   >credit,'accountType'=>$this->accountType);
        $this->db->insert('user',$array);

    }


     function checkUser(){

        $array=array(':username'=>$this->username);
        $results=$this->db->select('SELECT * FROM USER WHERE username=:username',$array);
        if(!empty($results)){
        $this->credit=$results[0]['credit'];
        $this->accountType=$results[0]['accountType'];
        }

        return $results;

    }

    function showAccountCredit() {
        echo 'Username: '.$this->username.'<br>';
        echo 'Account Credit: '.$this->credit.'<br>';
        echo 'Account Type: '.$this->accountType.'<br>';
    }

}
```

VIP account:

```
class VipUser extends User {

    function __construct($username) {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->username=$username;
        $this->credit='1000';
        $this->accountType='VIP Account';

        $data=$this->checkUser();

        if(!empty($data)){
            echo 'The username: '.$this->username.' already exists<br>';
            return false;
        }

        $array=array('username'=>$this->username, 'password'=>'password','credit'=> $this->credit,'accountType'=>$this->accountType);
        $this->db->insert('user',$array);

    }


     function checkUser(){

        $array=array(':username'=>$this->username);
        $results=$this->db->select('SELECT * FROM USER WHERE username=:username',$array);
        if(!empty($results)){
        $this->credit=$results[0]['credit'];
        $this->accountType=$results[0]['accountType'];
        }

        return $results;

    }

    function showAccountCredit() {
        echo 'Username: '.$this->username.'<br>';
        echo 'Account Credit: '.$this->credit.'<br>';
        echo 'Account Type: '.$this->accountType;
    }

}
```

UserFactory class

```
class UserFactory {

    static function create($username,$accountType){

        $accountType = strtolower($accountType);

        switch($accountType){
        case 'basic': return new BasicUser($username);
        case 'premium':return new PremiumUser($username);
        case 'vip': return new VipUser($username);
        default :return new BasicUser($username);
        }
    }
```

index.php

```
$user1= UserFactory::create('Jerry', 'Vip');
$user1->showAccountCredit();


$user2= UserFactory::create('Bob', 'Basic');
$user2->showAccountCredit();


$user3= UserFactory::create('Betty', 'premium');
$user3->showAccountCredit();
```

Comment: Why don't you put all the repeated code in the abstract user class itself ? And only the parts that change put those in the inheriting classes.

Comment: Are you running into a specific problem with your code? If not, and you simply want feedback, http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @interstellar_coder If I move my repeating codes to User class, I would have problem getting $username when I create my object for different account type.

Comment: @Colin Thanks for the advise. Is that possible you can transfer this thread for me?

Comment: @Rouge Sorry, I cannot. I think you'll have repost there.

Comment: Which problems with username? How about `Late Static Bindings`?

Comment: Rouge what problems are you experiencing ?

Comment: @Interstellar_coder and Igor. Thanks all. I just move my duplicated codes to my USER class. I think I am good now. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having 3 different implementations of user, consider 3 different implementations of "UserType". Separating responsibilities and composing objects together. Here's another pattern in action, called **strategy**.

```
function showAccountCredit(){
  return $this->type->showAccountCredit();
}
```

New class, UserType represents special behavior, User would then contain rest of generic stuff, reducing duplication you've described (or at least most of it)

**Factory** on the other hand can be used for loading objects from db:

```
class Loader{
  private $userTypeFactory;

  public function loadUser($id){
    $userRow = $db->loadRow();
    ...

    $userType = $userTypeFactory->$userRow["type"]();
    return new User($userType);
  }
}

class UserTypeFactory{
  public function vip(){
    return new VipUserType();
  }

  public function premium(){
    return new PremiumUser();
  }
}
```

You can go even step further and introduce IoC framework. Have a look on symfony2. Oh, and please dont use switch, rather do it like I did, polymorphism, dynamic calls.

---

**EDIT:**

**Strategy == wrapped behavior**. For example if you were checking user rights for seeing premium content, this is how it would usually look like:

```
class PagesController{
  ...

  public function showPage($id){
    ...
    if ($user->type == "premium" || $user->type == "vip"){
      ...
    }
    else if ($user->type == "credit"){
      $user->credits--;
      updateUser();
    }
    else{
      die("You do not have permissions to see this content...");
    }

    ... //render page
  }
}
```

And here's how it could look like using "strategy":

```
class PagesController{
  ...
  public function showPage($id){
    $page = ...;

    $user->pageRequested($page);

    //render page
  }
}

class User{
  private $userType;

  public function pageRequested($page){
    $this->userType->userRequestedPage($user, $page);
  }
}

class VipUserType{
  public function userRequestedPage($user, $page){
    //do nothing
  }
}

class PremiumUserType{
  public function userRequestedPage($user, $page){
    //do nothing
  }
}

class BasicUserType{
  public function userRequestedPage($user, $page){
    throw new Exception("You cant access this page");
  }
}

class CreditUserType{
  public function userRequestedPage($user, $page){
    $user->credit--;
    $user->save();
  }
}
```

This way, everything what's related to userType is separated, it's easy to add new types without risk of breaking existing types.

BTW: **This is nothing more than just plain old polymorphism.** Strategy is just another shiny word for OOP essentials, like most of patterns. Do not waste time thinking about patterns, they're good for inspiration however you'll gain much more experience from real OOP, have a look on smalltalk - http://www.pharo-project.org/home

Comment: Thanks for the help. Would you please be more specific on your strategy example? I don't really get it. Thanks. +1 though

Comment: um, you're welcome, if it was not irony :) otherwise I'm pretty busy so I can hardly afford those few minutes for writing up something, sorry for that.